# Solve this system of equations: $x^2 - y^2 = a^2\\ z^2 - y^2 = b^2\\ x^2 + z^2 = (a+b)^2$

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help me to solve this system of equations: 
$x^2 - y^2 = a^2\\
 z^2 - y^2 = b^2\\
x^2 + z^2 = (a+b)^2$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$x^2-z^2=x^2-y^2-(z^2-y^2)=?$

and we already have $x^2+z^2$

Can you solve the two simultaneous equations for $x^2,z^2?$